# cannot letsencrypt because port 80 auto redirects to 443

Tags: ssl, apache2

I have a few sites running on a server running apache2 and I have forgotten how I auto forwarded all traffic to https.  Trying to run letsencrypt but it must visit the http page first.  when I wget the page I receive:

`HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://example.org/ [following]`

I do not see anything in apache2.conf

**mysite.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin admin
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite/
 ServerName example.org

 Alias /mysite "/var/www/html/mysite/"

 <Directory /var/www/html/mysite/>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
      <IfModule mod_dav.c>
        Dav off
      </IfModule>
    SetEnv HOME /var/www/html/mysite
    SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/html/mysite
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

**mysite-le-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerAdmin admin
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite/
 ServerName mysite.org
 ServerAlias www.example.org
 Alias / "/var/www/html/mysite/"

 <Directory /var/www/html/mysite/>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
      <IfModule mod_dav.c>
        Dav off
      </IfModule>
    SetEnv HOME /var/www/html/mysite
    SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/html/mysite
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

 Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/oldsite/fullchain.pem
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/oldsite/privkey.pem
 </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin admin
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite/
 ServerName example.org
 ServerAlias www.example.org
 Alias / "/var/www/html/mysite/"

 <Directory /var/www/html/mysite/>
      <IfModule mod_dav.c>
        Dav off
      </IfModule>
    SetEnv HOME /var/www/html/mysite
    SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/html/mysite
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

not sure what I need to do to allow lets encrypt to complete the certs.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check your `.htaccess`. Redirects might be there too.

Comment: Checked .htaccess and there was nothing to redirect in there either...

Comment: Nothing what you show contains any redirects. This means the problem is in something you don't show. This can be .htaccess as suggested, it can be the application, it can be that you show the wrong config or skipped important parts which you deemed to unimportant ...  - hard to tell. The information to find out what happens are too incomplete.

Comment: Yep I was able to "fix" it last night.  I ended up going through and reinstalling apache2.  Not sure what I had done since it wasn't in the .htaccess or the site pages, but I felt the downtime was much better than the cert being out of date.  Reinstalled and was able to update other bits and pieces. Thanks for looking at my problem though!